# A failure to update latest version of Python (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, conda, updates

Failed to update Python to last version, either using Anaconda Navigator or command instructions that worked well for all other packages that needed updating

my (base) environment has python 3.11.3.  Anaconda Navigator fails to update it to 3.11.4.  The commands

```
conda clean --all
conda update --all
```

work well for cleaning and find correctly that 3.11.3 needs update to 3.11.4, namely

```
The following packages will be updated:
python   3.11.3-h966fe2a_0 --> 3.11.4-h966fe2a_0
```

when proceeding, conda updates all items but Python, with the error message:

```
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(952): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python-3.11.4-h966fe2a_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LookupError('unknown encoding: utf-16-le')
```

Comment: Are you able to create a conda env with `python=3.11.4`?

Comment: also, could you add the output of `conda info` to your question?

Comment: Yes I can create an environment with 3.11.4